# how to get open-uri works in a rails project (asked by a newbie)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

my spec :

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe Category, type: :model do
  before { @category = FactoryGirl.build(:category) }
  subject { @category }
  ...
```

my factory :

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :category do
    title { FFaker::Lorem.word }
    picture { FFaker::Avatar.image }
  end
end
```

my gem file :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem "devise"
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'sabisu_rails', github: "IcaliaLabs/sabisu-rails"
gem 'furatto', github: "IcaliaLabs/furatto-rails"
gem 'active_model_serializers', github: 'rails-api/active_model_serializers', branch: '0-8-stable'
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.3"
gem 'open_uri_redirections'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'ffaker'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'sqlite3'

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '2.5.0', require: false
  gem 'rspec-collection_matchers'
end

end
```

what I got running this command =>

```
bundle exec rspec spec/models/category_spec.rb is :

Randomized with seed 44232 FFFFF Failures: 

1) Category 
 Failure/Error: before { @category = FactoryGirl.build(:category) }

 RuntimeError: redirection forbidden: robohash.org/debitismagnamodio.png?size=300x300 -> robohash.org/debitismagnamodio.png?size=300x300
```

the factory can't create the object because it calls FFake::Avatar.image which is an url (I think, I'm not sure). I already required open-uri and open_uri_redirections both in the factory and the spec but it doesn't work.

any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in to you Gemfile

gem 'open_uri_redirections', git: 'git@github.com:open-uri-redirections/open_uri_redirections.git'

after
bundle update open_uri_redirections